# Every positive integer is a limit point of the sequence $a_n=n-\sqrt{n}\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have the following sequence and limit:

$$\left(a_n\right)=\left(n-\sqrt{n}\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right\rfloor\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\left(\sqrt{n^2+2\ell}-n\right)}=\ell,$$

where $\ell$ is natural (i.e., $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$).

I have to prove that any natural number is a partial limit of the sequence $\left(a_n\right)$.

As I understand, I have to find a sequence of indexes that include $\ell$, that I can use to prove the claim. I've found a sequence of indexes that leads to a solution, but it is not a set of natural numbers. I can't get over this problem and build a sequence of natural indexes.

I thought of this 4 days, and I can't solve it, so I'm asking for help. This was my best solution, but the indexes are not natural numbers:

$$ \left(a_n\right)=\left(n-\sqrt{n}\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right\rfloor\right)= \sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right\rfloor\right) $$
$$ \left(n_k\right)={\left(n+\frac {\ell}{n}\right)}^2$$
$$a_{n_k}=\sqrt{{\left(n+\frac {\ell}{n}\right)}^2}\left(\sqrt{{\left(n+\frac {\ell}{n}\right)}^2}-\left\lfloor{\sqrt{{\left(n+\frac {\ell}{n}\right)}^2}}\right\rfloor\right)=$$
$$=\left(n+\frac {\ell}{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+2\ell+\frac {\ell^2}{n^2}}-\lfloor{n+\frac {\ell}{n}}\rfloor\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(n+\frac {\ell}{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+2\ell+\frac {l^2}{n^2}}-\lfloor{n+\frac {\ell}{n}}\rfloor\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\left(\sqrt{n^2+2\ell}-n\right)}=\ell$$

Comment: Why do you have to prove this?

Comment: As an exercise in the univercity

Comment: Please give the exercise directly indstead of just a link.

Comment: And they're not expecting you to do your homework by yourself?

Comment: I thought of this 4 days, and I can't solve it, so I'm asking for help

Comment: In the current form of your question, you're not asking for help, you're asking that someone else will do it for you. Asking for help means showing what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: This was my best solution

Comment: http://prnt.sc/bx1h79

Comment: Then post it as part of the question.

Comment: Please, visit the Help Center for formatting tips http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and type your math in the body of your question instead of using links

Comment: the first sequence is clearly divergent with $a_n\sim \sqrt{n}$ if $n$ is close to a perfect square

Comment: I've edited the question. Can it be reopened?

Comment: Now it's good, (+1) for the question. However, it's not immediately clear to me what's the problem, so I'll leave it for the others

Comment: The phrasing of the question is suboptimal and the solution proposed above turns around the good idea but spoils it by too much imprecision, however... all in all and after some amount of deciphering and head scratching, it seems that the question asks to show that for every positive integer $\ell$ there exists some subsequence $(a_{n(k)})$ of $(a_n)$ such that $a_{n(k)}\to\ell$ when $k\to\infty$ and provides a hint to do so (the limit in the second line). To answer this, define $$n(k)=k^2+2\ell$$ and note that, for every $k\geqslant\ell$, $\lfloor \sqrt{n(k)}\rfloor=k$ ...

Comment: ... hence $$a_{n(k)}=k^2+2\ell-\sqrt{k^2+2\ell}\cdot k=2\ell-k\cdot(\sqrt{k^2+2\ell}-k).$$ By the indication provided, $k\cdot(\sqrt{k^2+2\ell}-k)\to\ell$ when $k\to\infty$ hence, as desired, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n(k)}=\ell.$$